# Aiml emoji support

Tags: chatbot, aiml

How to use pandorabots emoji.set and emojinormal.txt to support emoji in aiml?

```
<category>
<pattern><set>emoji</set></pattern>
<template></template>
</category>
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: This looks okay. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Emoji recognization. Does this work in program ab?

Comment: Without wanting to sound like "that guy", wouldn't it be worth trying it first and then post if you have any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this you have to put emoji in hex code instead of raw emoji inside template like this.

```
<category>
   <pattern>_ watch # movies # pc #</pattern>
   <template>Sometimes &#x1F601;.</template>
</category>
```

It will generate output like this

```
Human: do u watch movies in ur pc
Robot: Sometimes .
```